# MenuBar never option

Tags: android

I'm building an app with AndroidStudio.
I have a problem with my Menu.

This is my menu file .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Logout"/>
</menu>
```

This is that I can see from Preview:

[image]

In my activity main, I have this code to create this menu:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public MyDatabase db;
    public ProgressDialog dialog;
    public String url="";
    private static final Intent SCAN_INTENT = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.care_home, menu);
        if (menu != null) {

        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }   
}
```

But if I try to start my application I can see this:

[image]

As you can see, I can't see icon of application and I can't see Option menu.
How can I do this?

Comment: post your activity from start ...

Comment: You have to use `Toolbar` in your `Activity` and then add that toolbar as a `ActionBar` in your `Activity`

Comment: See my answer you are using toolbar or action but extending the activity which won't allow the toolbar to appear.

Answer (score 0):

First extend your activity with `AppCompatActivity` rather `Activity` like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
```

And return `return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));` it rather `true` like:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.care_home, menu);
        if (menu != null) {

        }
        return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are extending Activity only that's why you are unable to see the toolbar or action.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {}
```

instead use this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
```

For more please read the android documentation about appBars:
[Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may use lower version android device for that press hardware menu button of device it will shows your menu.My suggestion is to test it on at least above on jelly bean .

Answer (score 0):

Extend **AppCompatActivity** not Activity. and create menu like below:

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.care_home, menu);
    return return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);;
}
```

and care_home.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_logout"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Logout"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

For setting **AppBar** you can read [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html).